# add-in for outlook to covert a video file to gif

Tags: outlook, converters, add-in, gif

I want to make an add-in for outlook to covert a video file to gif which has two functionality to save the video file as gif image and attach the the gif in the mail body as attachment and thumbnail.

Please give me idea to do this and what component I need to use and architecture.

Thanks in advance...I am sure you I can have a great ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

To get started building add-ins for Outlook you will need Visual Studio:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386094.aspx

You can use the Attachments collection to add files to an email:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh290845.aspx

For more information about building solutions for Outlook, see:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg608200.aspx#OLSelectAPI_InOrOut

Comment: Hi Eric,
Thanks for the information , I have proceeded to some extent on my own ..hope these contents will help me more.. :)
BR//Arindam